# How to access Google Cloud Token Service API with a Service Account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, refresh-token, google-identity-toolkit

I am trying to use this API through a service account.

```
https://securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token?key=[API_KEY]
```

Reference:
https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/use-rest-api#section-refresh-token

The problem is that I keep having the `403 FORBIDDEN` error when trying to call it with credentials generated from my service account.

```
{"error"=>{"code"=>403, "message"=>"Request had insufficient authentication scopes.", "status"=>"PERMISSION_DENIED", "details"=>[{"@type"=>"type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo", "reason"=>"ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT", "domain"=>"googleapis.com", "metadata"=>{"method"=>"google.identity.securetoken.v1.SecureToken.GrantToken", "service"=>"securetoken.googleapis.com"}}]}}
```

Here is what I checked.

- My `Token Service API` is enabled on my GCP project.
- My service account has the `owner` role.
- When calling it with an API key, no problem with using the API (but I want to make it work with a service account...)

Here is the code that I am trying to make it work.

```rb
      SCOPE = %w[
        https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase
        https://www.googleapis.com/auth/identitytoolkit
      ]
  
      def initialize
        decoded_service_account_json = Base64.decode64(ENV.fetch("GCP_JSON_KEYFILE_BASE64"))
        io = StringIO.new(decoded_service_account_json)
        @credentials = Google::Auth::DefaultCredentials.make_creds(scope: SCOPE, json_key_io: io)
      end

      # Exchange a refresh token for an ID token
      # References:
      #  - https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v1/accounts/accounts/getIdpAuthentication
      def exchange_refresh_token(refresh_token)
        uri = URI.parse("https://securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token")
        http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
        http.use_ssl = true

        request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path, { 'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' })
        request.body = URI.encode_www_form(
          'grant_type' => 'refresh_token',
          'refresh_token' => refresh_token
        )

        request.add_field('Authorization', @credentials.apply({})[:authorization])

        response = http.request(request)
        response_data = JSON.parse(response.body)

        if response.code.to_i == 200
          {
            id_token: response_data['id_token'],
            refresh_token: response_data['refresh_token'],
            expires_at: Time.now + response_data['expires_in'].to_i
          }
        else
          raise TokenExchangeError.new("Token exchange failed: #{response.code} - #{response_data['error_description']}")
        end
      end
```

Do you have any idea why it does not work? Or perhaps `Token Service API` cannot work with a service account?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you trying this code from a compute engine?

Comment: The key is in the error message `insufficient authentication scopes`. Review the scopes you declared when creating credentials. You need the `cloud-platform` scope.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere No, I run this locally from my machine.
@JohnHanley Yes, that's what I thought. Problem is Token Service API does not specify the necessary scopes anywhere in the documentation. Unfortunately, adding `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform` to my `SCOPE` didn't work.

My service account already has the `owner` role so should be able to have all permissions.

Comment: If you don't request a scope, you won't get the permission even if the service account has been granted the corresponding IAM role. Note: The `owner` role does not have all permissions. That is a popular incorrect assumption.

Comment: @JohnHanley
Thank you very much for your help. It led me to finding the solution.

Comment: You are welcome. I think you have run into a newish feature due to Google's work on federation that has not been updated in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution by playing around and making guesses as the documentation was not providing any useful information.

**I needed to add the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/securetoken` scope in my `SCOPE` in order to be able to use `https://securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token`.**

```
SCOPE = %w[
        https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase
        https://www.googleapis.com/auth/identitytoolkit
        https://www.googleapis.com/auth/securetoken
      ]
  
      def initialize
        decoded_service_account_json = Base64.decode64(ENV.fetch("GCP_JSON_KEYFILE_BASE64"))
        io = StringIO.new(decoded_service_account_json)
        @credentials = Google::Auth::DefaultCredentials.make_creds(scope: SCOPE, json_key_io: io)
      end
```

That was completely a random guess...
I checked all the possible scopes here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes

But `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/securetoken` is not one of them. Even Google Search does not return any relevant information for the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/securetoken` scope.

This is quite frustrating. Could someone tell me if there is a way I could have found the solution without guessing? Where does `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/securetoken` come from?

Comment: Very interesting solution!